# MySQL MAX Date - Single join table - Only selects first fkUserId match

Tags: mysql

Simple join table -

```
CREATE TABLE tbluserstomaintasks  (
fkUserId INT(6),
fkMainTaskId INT(6),
UpdateTimestamp TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO tbluserstomaintasks (fkUserId, fkMainTaskId, UpdateTimestamp) VALUES (1, 1, '2015-02-03 16:40:00');
INSERT INTO tbluserstomaintasks (fkUserId, fkMainTaskId,  UpdateTimestamp) VALUES (1, 2, '2015-02-03 16:47:00');
INSERT INTO tbluserstomaintasks (fkUserId, fkMainTaskId, UpdateTimestamp) VALUES (1, 2, '2015-02-03 16:53:00');
INSERT INTO tbluserstomaintasks (fkUserId, fkMainTaskId, UpdateTimestamp) VALUES (2, 1, '2015-02-03 17:01:00');
```

SQL SELECT to query the newest UpdateTimestamp for one specific fkUserId

```
SELECT  p2.fkUserId, p2.fkMainTaskId, p2.UpdateTimestamp
FROM tbluserstomaintasks AS p2
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT fkUserId, fkMainTaskId, MAX(UpdateTimestamp) AS Value
  FROM tbluserstomaintasks
  GROUP BY fkUserId)
 AS p1
 ON p1.fkUserId = p2.fkUserId AND p1.Value = p2.UpdateTimestamp
 WHERE p2.fkUserId = 1
```

Result

fkUserID  fkMainTaskId  UpdateTimestamp
1         2             2015-02-03 16:53:00

I'm looking for a result set with two records, one with fkMainTaskId = 1 (UpdateTimestamp = 2015-02-03 16:40:00) and a second with fkMainTaskId = 2 (UpdateTimestamp = 2015-02-03 16:53:00).

Attempt #2:
Moved 'WHERE fkUserId=1' to the interior SELECT with the same result as attempt #1.

Attempt #3:
Removed the first ON clause from the outer SELECT (p1.fkUserId = p2.fkUserId) with the same result as attempt #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work for you. You want to have a row per user and task id, with the maximum timestamp for each.

```
SELECT  p2.fkUserId, p2.fkMainTaskId, MAX(p2.UpdateTimestamp)
FROM tbluserstomaintasks AS p2
WHERE p2.fkUserId = 1
GROUP BY p2.fkUserId, p2.fkMainTaskId
```

Comment: Worked well.  It looks like the GROUP BY values are the key here to getting the multiple record results?

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to explain that with 'You want to have a row per user and task id', but that wasn't very clear.